# Visual Studio Code "Python is not installed. Please download and install Python before using the extension." Error

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code on Windows and I get an error like this: Python is not installed. Please download and install Python before using the extension. But I Already Have Python 3.10.2 What Should I Do? [Screenshot Of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKBdR.png)

Comment: Have you restarted your PC since the install? On Windows the `$PATH` environment variable only gets loaded on startup, so the new install of Python might not be "visible" yet

Comment: What's the result of `python --version`  in the terminal out of the VSCode?

Comment: The result is: `Python 3.10.2`

Comment: Same problem here. Python IS in the path. I can run both python --version and python3 --version in the terminal inside VS Code and it works. But it keeps saying Python is not installed when starting VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

you probably installed Python from windows store. Please install from [python website](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). Make sure to mark `Add Python 3.X to PATH` during installation. Then reopen your VScode.

[image]

Comment: i already add to path variable but it didnt works

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue and it is fixed by below sequence

1. click search source
2. enter "> Python: Select Interpreter"
3. Select Python execute file you already installed